# Stella and the president's secret notes

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus, geography

> **Jason Trump**, president of the Untitled Statues Association, has left a notebook containing presumably important information lying around on his desk. **Stella**, his nosy assistant, takes a look only to see that the notes have been encrypted into image form.
>
> [image]
> [image]

Can you help Stella uncover what secret plans the president has?

---

<sub>Image credits: Row1 #6 Hakanand cc-by-sa 3.0; row 2 #2 Bff cc-by-sa 3.0; #3 Stilfehler cc-by-sa 3.0; row 3 #1 Jik jik cc-by-sa 3.0; #2 F. Lamiot, cc-by-sa 3.0; #5 Hasanbardal cc-by-sa 4.0; row 4 #2 M.Minderhoud, cc-by-sa 3.0; #4 John Lykkegaard, cc-by-sa 2.5; #6 David Steele cc-by-sa 2.0.</sub>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Trump's plans involve ...

> ... **firing Stella**.

**Step 1**

> Solve the rebuses. (Omega Krypton and commenters have solved a greate deal of those already. Since I'm one of the commenters, I have no qualms about reproducing the answers here for the sake of completeness.):
>
>  1a. **SIMMONS**: yes in Portuguese + Olympus {Mons}
>  2a. **RABBIT**: Rabbi + T
>  3a. **CASINO**: from 007 film/novel "Casino Royale"
>  4a. **'S**: Missing from McDonald{'s} and {'s}-Gravenhage
>  5a. **TREE**: here, a binary search tree
>  6a. **SHEEP**: Female sign + Extended Play record (EP)
>
>  1b. **BAND**: Bandy - Y
>  2b. **DISH**: Radish - sun god RA
>  3b. **WHEEL**: W (from keyboard layout) + heel
>  4b. **ELEVEN**: {EL} Salvador + even, i.e. not odd
>  5b. **MATERIAL**: (check) mate + (Saudi-Arabian) Rial
>  6b. **MINDER**: min (not max) + de(e)r
>
>  1c. **SCOTTISH**: Bon Scott (AC/DC singer) + (f)ish
>  2c. **LARGEST**: Last (but not least) around berge - BA
>  3c. **THIRD**: Third major minus major (army rank)
>  4c. **VLADIMIR**: Vlad (the Impaler) + I + Mir (space station)
>  5c. **NETFLIX**: net + FL (Florida) + IX
>  6c. **ROMAN**: Romaina - IA
>
>  1d. **GIRL**: G (giga) + IR (infra-red) + L (large size)
>  2d. **CAT**: cast minus its 3rd letter
>  3d. **POWER**: V·I = P
>  4d. **ILYICH**: (lily - L) + (rich - R)
>  5d. **AND**: South African Rand - 1st letter
>  6d. **GARMENT**: last 60% of cigar (note box!) + (regi|condi|detri)-ment

**Step 2**

> Pair up a/b and c/d answers and answer these:
>
>  Simmons band – **KISS**
>  Rabbit dish – **STEW**
>  Casino wheel – **ROULETTE**
>  ...'s eleven – **OCEAN**
>  Tree material – **WOOD**
>  Sheep minder – **SHEPHERD**
>
>  Scottish girl – **LASS**
>  Largest cat – **TIGER**
>  Third power – **CUBE**
>  Vladimir Ilyich – **LENIN**
>  Netflix and ... – **CHILL**
>  Roman garment – **TOGA**

**Step 3**

> You can prepend a nationality to all a/b answers to get familiar expressions. You can turn all c/d answers to a country name by chaning one letter. Then take the first letters of the nationality and the changed letters from the answers:
>
>  **F**rench KISS
>   **I** rish STEW
>  **R**ussian ROULETTE
>   **I** ndian OCEAN
>  **N**orwegian WOOD
>  **G**erman SHEPHERD
>
>  LA**S**S / Laos
>  **T**IGER / Niger
>  CUB**E** / Cuba
>  **L**ENIN / Benin
>  CHIL**L** / Chile
>  TOG**A** / Togo

Credit where it's due:

> Omega Krypton solved many of the rebusses and where they weren't solved completely, provided useful bits of Google legwork such as the rial in Arabic and the image of Ra. (I had particular difficulties interpreting the stroke through "max" and "odd" as opposite, not as removal of letters.) Omega's numerous commenters have contributed greatly to that answer and therefore also to mine. Finally, kl78 and Bananenkopp pointed out the last missing bits in comments to my anser. Thanks, y'all!

Comment: Explanation for Bon + a flash should be Bon Scott of AC/DC, because they have the flash in the band name and Bon Scott was singer till he died 1980

Comment: maybe the "missing word" from #4, which is obvious, could be the solution for your Step 2, and the nationality would be indian for step 3

Comment: Thanks, you two. I think I have it wrapped up now. (I'll pardon myself for not getting the AC/DC reference, but not seeing how #4 works is inexcusable ...)

Answer (score 10):

Thanks must be given to @GarethMcCaughan, @MOehm, @tmpearce, @Belhenix for helping me with some of the rebuses and clues in the comments

### Part I - Rebuses

1.

> **SIM CITY**: Sim (yes in Portuguese, hinted by word colour) + City (olympus city) or **SIMMONS**: Sim + Mons (Olympus Mons)

2.

> **RABBIT**: the man was *Rabbi* Moshe/Moses Feinstein + T

3.

> **CASINO**: Casino Royale (007) (film)

4.

> **SS**: McDonald('s) + (s-)Gravenhage

5.

> **TREE**: a binary search tree

6.

> **FROM**: F (female) + ROM

7.

> **BAND**: Bandy - Y

8.

> **DISH**: Radish - Ra
> Can't resist this vulgar guess :P {**BLOODY NORA??** (Red) beetroot and (No) a prohibit symbol with (Ra)}

9.

> **WHEEL**: W (missing letter in keyboard layout) + Heel [not Plantar Fasciitis!]

10.

> **ELEVEN**: El [Salvador] + Even (not odd) [Note: I like this one!]

11.

> **MATERIAL**: MATE + RIAL (variant of Saudi riyal currency of Saudi Arabia)

12.

> **MINDER**: min (not max) + Deer - e

14.

> **LARGEST**: LAST (last but not least) outside RGE (barge-ba)

15.

> **THIRD**: Third major - major (rank)

16.

> **VLADIMIR**: [Vlad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vlad_the_Impaler) + I + MIR

17.

> **NETFLIX**: net + fl (florida) + ix (9 in Roman numerals)

18.

> **ROMAN**: Romania - ia

19.

> **GIRL**: G (giga) + IR (infrared) + L (large size)

20.

> **CAT??**: cast - third letter (-3.)

21.

> **POWER**: V $\times$ I = Power

22.

> **ILYICH**: Lily - L + Rich (wealthy) - r

23.

> **AND**: ZAR = South Africa *Rand* (ahem, @Rand Al'Thor), diagram underneath asks us to remove first letter

24.

> **GARMENT**: end part of cigar + ment (regiment, condiment, detriment)

### Part II - Interpretation

> It looks like we should read the rebuses in pairs (up-down).
>  SIMMONS BAND --> **KISS**
>  RABBIT DISH --> **STEW**
>  CASINO WHEEL --> **ROULETTE/ BIGS**
>  SS ELEVEN --> **WICKFORD** [(post code)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SS_postcode_area)
>  TREE MATERIAL --> **WOOD/ PAPER**
>  ? MINDER -->
>  ? GIRL -->
>  LARGEST CAT --> **SIBERIAN/ TIGER/ LION**
>  THIRD POWER --> **CUBE**
>  [VLADIMIR ILYICH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Lenin) --> **USSR(/ LENIN?)**
>  NETFLIX AND --> **CHILL**
>  ROMAN GARMENT --> **TUNIC (/TOGA?)**

Something I'm not sure about:

> It seems like the majority of the answers for the interpretation is 4, 5 or 8 letters long. Is this true for all cases? Or maybe a [word-ladder](/questions/tagged/word-ladder)?

Comment: Don't reinvent the Plantar fascitis.

Comment: perhaps a different part of the foot, as per MOehm's comment. I think you've left the R in Ilyich, and in view of that one you should take a look at the box above it.

Comment: In 8 I'm pretty sure you've mis-identified the vegetable.

Comment: (On the other hand I'm pretty sure you've correctly identified the god.)

Comment: Nope :-). I think the "no" symbol just means the sort of letter-removal one sees all the time in rebuses.

Comment: On 14, I think you should indeed be thinking about "large", but also about another word beginning with "la".

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the second thing in 6 is not a ROM and I suspect that you should have Beyonce in mind, but I also suspect these things pair up with their neighbours above or below and the answer I'm thinking of for 6 doesn't fit with what I'm fairly sure 12 is.

Comment: It's the rest of your barge inside "what is not least" from that saying. Try a Latinized variant of SAR in 11. Note where exactly the red box is in 24 (top).

Comment: For #1 you might also consider rot13(fvz + bylzchf ZBAF = fvzzbaf)

Comment: #24: rot13(pvTNE + ZRAG = TNEZRAG: ebzna tnezrag = GBTN?)

Comment: #16 rot13(iynq+v+zve (+vylvpu = YRAVA?))

Comment: [I don't think](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netflix_and_chill) that your 4-letter assumption holds. Assuming that the record in #6 is an Extended Play breaks it further.

Comment: #15 rot13(P naq R = znwbe guveq - znwbe = GUVEQ + cbjre = PHOR?)

Comment: #4: rot13(gur gjb 'f' sebz zpqbanyq'f naq f-⁠Tenirauntr ner zvffvba, fb V'z thrffvat vg'f FF?)